# Do you have to subtract the skirt board width when measuring stair width?

Tags: framing, code-compliance, stairs

It's my understanding that if you have 3' wide treads and you put drywall on top you no longer meet code because your stair width is now 2-11". Is that also true for skirt board?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The skirt boards do not count. The drywall does, it needs to finish out at 36" or more. The framing needs to start at 37" for 1/2" drywall. If the drywall is thicker for some reason, the framing must be wider to accommodate.

According to [IBC 2018 R311.7](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch03_SecR311.7)

Anything above the handrail height up until the headroom height needs to be a minimum of 36" wide. Anything at or below the handrail height the minimum width is 31.5" if there's one handrail or 27" if there are 2 handrails. As long as the skirt board isn't obnoxiously thick to reduce the width below 31.5" or 27" it's fine.

Comment: Do you have anything to support this? I believe this is correct but I haven't found anything to back it up in my searches.

Comment: It is in the code book It will take a few minutes, but I can add it to the answer

Comment: https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch03_SecR311         Please go to R311.7 Stairways. I do not know how the get this page in the answer This is the actual building code site.

Comment: I edited your answer with the link and my interpretation. Thanks.

Comment: You did very well